# linkedin oauth authorization fails with "Bummer, something went wrong"

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

[Bummer, something went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE2DG.png)

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=test&redirect_uri=http://test.custom.com/abc/linkedin&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424asgTyhgTR5

when I use the above url I am getting "Bummer, something went wrong.
We're having difficulty connecting."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello I had a similar problem and I fixed it by doing this ;

You have to ensure that everything in your APP page ( https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps ) matches the parameters in your authorization URL . SO for example in your case , https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=test&redirect_uri=http://test.custom.com/abc/linkedin&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424asgTyhgTR5 ;

You would have to ensure that your client_id in the auth URL matches the Client-Id on your APP page and also ensure that the redirect_uri you specified in your auth URL has been authorized on your app page as shown below . If you are passing in scopes as well, also ensure that they match perfectly . As you can see in the image below , my redirect_uri has been authorized from my app page . 
[image]

Comment: Alright . I am glad it did . Please mark my answer as accepted so that it helps others who have a similar problem

Comment: hello @SayoPaul; i'm having same error with this link:  https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=86bj3533uge611&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2callback&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile

Comment: on my linkeding page , Authorized Redirect  is setted to : http://localhost/callback

Comment: hello there @stackdave . There is a typo in the redirect_uri in your authorization URL . As you can see I corrected the typo and this link works fine https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=86bj3533uge611&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost/callback&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile . Please if it helps you out , upvote the answer to help others too

Comment: @SayoPaul when i click on the last link u posted i also still get bummer something went wrong does it work on your side still?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=78kst582fc....&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile


here is my like and also struggling to get the authentication code

Comment: Hello, please I entered the link provided and it says invalid client id

Answer (score 16):

You need to add the "Sign In with LinkedIn" permission.

- Go to your app page
- Go to the products tab (for your app, not at the top; there are two)
- Select "Request Access" on the "Sign In with LinkedIn" product and the "Share on LinkedIn" product. This will give access to the following permissions: r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, w_member_social.

Answer (score 2):

The best is to inspect how is the link generated by linkedin developer tool for you and then you just have to change the redirect url

https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth

then "create token" then select all permission and click on "Request access token"
if you have the development window open you can see a query authorisation is done, then you can just copy this url and change the redirect_url.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxWam.png)

so for me
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=myredirectid&scope=r_emailaddress%2Cr_liteprofile%2Cw_member_social&state=e6c0e1c8-1a35-478f-8eea-b0412a6675c9

Answer (score 1):

Recreate a application after 12/15/2018 solved the problem for me.
(Any developer application created through the LinkedIn Developer Portal after December 15, 2018 automatically has access to the v2 API.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn has deprecated that old authentication, now you need to use the **OpenID** connect product, for that you need to use linkedin-openid in the route instead of linkedin:

```
From: http://localhost:8000/linkedin/callback
To: http://localhost:8000/linkedin-openid/callback
```

also don't forget to request access for "**Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect**" product

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I ran into same issue.

Changing value of `redirect_uri` in linkedin app from `http` to `https` helped solved the issue. See picture below:

[image: Linkedin App OAuth 2.0 Settings]

---

In your case, url should have been:

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=test&redirect_uri=http**s**://test.custom.com/abc/linkedin&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424asgTyhgTR5 ;